# PHP SQL Loop Returns PHP Code

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a HMTL select box which populates from a table in a SQL database.

This is my test code:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'apassword');
mysql_select_db('webforms');

$sql = "SELECT site FROM sites_rcs";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='sub1'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value '" . $row['site'] ."'>" . $row['site'] ."</option>";
    }
echo "</select>"            

</body>
```

When I open this page in a web browser I get this result:

```
"; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo "" . $row['site'] .""; } echo ""
```

I have tried rewriting the code from various examples provided on the internet:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVl5GPpMJsY
http://www.yourwebskills.com/mysqldropdown.php

When I run the query `SELECT site FROM sites_rcs` in phpMyAdmin it returns the values in a list.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is not closing tag for `<?php`. add it `?>` before `</body>`. and change `echo "</select>" ` to `echo "</select>";`

Comment: Multiple syntax errors... Missing closing `;` in your `echo "</select>"` and you aren't closing your php either, add `?>` after the last echo.

Comment: Please dont use the `mysql_` database extensions, they are deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions, 
[and here is why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: one you are missing a semicolon after this `echo "</select>"`, also close the php code `?>` and finaly maybe you are trying to use mysql_fetch_assoc for associative array result.

Comment: If the file extension on this script is not `.php` then change it to `.php` and apache will send the php code to the php interpreter for compile and execution

Comment: @RiggsFolly, we need a campaign for this! The problem is `mysql` is taking over the all web development tutorials. Sites provides tutorials has outdated articles, and at `mysql`era. The biggest problem is that newbies who tend using free hosting solutions which don't provide `mysqli` (there are few tho)

Comment: @AdamAzad Agreed. It will probably take years or at least until PHP7 is well bedded in and the default option on all standard hosting packages.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for all your responses. It was the issue that it was a .html file and not .php I had being misinformed when I was told by a colleague that you can run php code inside a html file. The syntax issues have also been fixed and it is now workin as expected. I will look into learning the new mysqli/PDO commands over the deprecated commands.

Answer (score 0):

Is PHP installed on the web server? Looks like the server just responds with the contents of your php file. Have a look at the page source.

Answer (score 0):

1- Make sure you have a server with php installed. 
2- Make sure your file is .php not .html 
3- Make sure your server is running
4- If testing on a local machine, make sure you're running the file through the server and not by double clicking it